# How to update an Ajax call depending on button clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have the following HTML code where I have incorporated Bootstrap Tabs/Pills. My goal is to have the user see a data count from the previous day and the last seven days depending on which tab they select. I have a working AJAX call which pulls in a Count from the last 24hrs and from the last 7 days.

However, whenever I click on the 'Week' tab; the data still show the data from day-time. Can some advise where I am going wrong?

Thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 border rounded">     
  <h4><u>Count </u></h4>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" onclick="$('#time_runs').text('day-time')" href="#today_num">Day</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" onclick="$('#time_runs').text('week-time')" href="#week_num">Week</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

AJAX Call:

```
$(document).ready(function getMetadata() {
    $(function poll() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<!--#include virtual="../include/env"-->/count/" +  ($('#time_runs').text() == '' ? 'day-time' : $('#time_runs').text()),
        type: "GET",
        cache: "false",
        success: function(data) {
          count(data);
        },
        dataType: "json"
      });
    })
  })
  ;
```

Comment: how are you invoking the poll() function? And why is it wrapped in a `$(`??. It looks like you may be calling this function once when the page loads, and never calling it afterwards. You need to ensure the function is called when the user chooses a tab.

Comment: Hi ADyson, 
1. The poll() function was added in error. I have removed it from my code
2. I was under the impression the $() was the correct syntax to call an id?
3. This was my assumption too. Is it something to do with the $(document).ready? How would you advise the code should look?

Comment: "$() was the correct syntax to call an id?" ...that syntax invokes the jQuery constructor, which is usually used to select elements... but you are using it to wrap round a function definition which doesn't, in this context, make a lot of sense.

Comment: $(document).ready is used to wrap round a code block whose execution you want to delay until the page is fully loaded (e.g. to set event handlers on elements, while ensuring those elements are loaded when the handler is declared). Perhaps you need to brush up on your jQuery and JavaScript basics before you continue

Comment: If you are prepared to be patient then when I next get in front of a computer I'll knock together a code example for you. Am on mobile right now so it's hard to type it and pretty much impossible to test

Comment: Thanks. I am quite new to coding and I fully take on-board your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it entirely using Bootstrap's built-in tabs functionality. See the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/) for more info.

Note I've used a dummy URL here which will always return the same data, but that's just a detail - the important points here are

a) setting up the tabs correctly as per the docs

b) responding to the "tab shown" event so you can trigger a new request to get the count

c) storing the value which you send to the server to tell it what data to return in a data-attribute of the tab, rather than messing about setting and then reading the value of another separate field.

N.B. Design note: You might want to consider caching the data and/or pre-loading these counts into the page rather than making an AJAX request every time a tab is shown. Since you appear to have a fixed number of tabs and the count data is small, it seems inefficient to keep firing off a HTTP request to fetch this tiny bit of data every time the user clicks a tab. Unless this data is being changed on the server every few seconds it's unlikely to produce a different result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
    var time = $(this).data("time");
    console.log(time);
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/zzirx?time=" + time,
      type: "GET",
      cache: "false",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      dataType: "json"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 border rounded">
    <h4><u>Count </u></h4>

    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="day-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-time="day-time" href="#day" role="tab" aria-controls="day" aria-selected="true">Day</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="profile-week" data-toggle="tab" data-time="week-time" href="#week" role="tab" aria-controls="week" aria-selected="false">Week</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="day" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Day</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="week" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Week</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ADyson, It works thank you. However my Day Tab doesn't load by default when the page is ready. I have to select the Day Tab for it show. I see that doesn't happen in your example. Where in your code, loads Day when the document is ready? (In case I have missed something)

Comment: `<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="day"` ...note the "show" and "active" classes there. And similar on the link - `<a class="nav-link active"`. Check whether you've set that correctly in your version

Comment: Hmmm. they are configured as you have above. But still need to click on it for the data to actually show.

Comment: Maybe you have some other CSS which is hiding it or something? I can't really tell without seeing it, it must be something non-obvious. If you can create a CodePen or JSFiddle demo of your code which reproduces the issue then maybe I could help you figure it out.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Here is an example using your code with a couple of changes here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1zagutr/64/):

1. Add an id to your `ul` in this example we are going to use `#nav-pills`.
2. Add a data attribute called `selected` to your `ul` element.
3. on each of your on click I change this `onclick="$('#time_runs').text('week-time')"`  for this  `onclick="return $('#nav-pills').data('selected','today')"`.
4. Since we dont now what executes your poll function I add a delegation event on your `ul` like this `$('#nav-pills').on('click','li>a'`.

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
$('#nav-pills').on('click','li>a',(e)=>{
//your ajax call here instead of this example one
let time = $('#nav-pills').data("selected");
console.log(time);
json = {
today:"todays log yay!!!",
weak:"a Weak ago log,lets rock"
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {time: time, json:JSON.stringify(json)}
  }).done((response)=>{
  console.log(time,response)
  })
})
})
```

```html
 

   <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-4 border rounded">     
  <h4><u>Count </u></h4>
  <ul id="nav-pills" class="nav nav-pills" data-selected="">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" onclick="return $('#nav-pills').data('selected','today')" href="#today_num">Day</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" onclick="return $('#nav-pills').data('selected','weak')" href="#week_num">Week</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope it helps